# Select a random element of an enum in D

Tags: d

I have taken to selecting random values from enums like so:

```
import std.random : uniform;
import std.stdio : writefln;
import std.conv;

enum E {A, B, C}

int main(){
    auto select = cast(E)uniform(to!int(E.min), to!int(E.max));
    writefln("select %s", select);
    return 0;
}
```

This is surprisingly verbose, and prone to issues if any enum members take values outside the default (or larger than `int`).

Ideally I would take a range that represents the elements of the enum, and provide this to `randomSample`. However, this doesn't appear to be possible.

Is there a more idiomatic way to select  a random value from an enum in D?

**EDIT:**

Using the answer provided by fwend, here is a template function that achieves what I want:

```
T RandomEnumElement(T)() if (is(T == enum)){
    auto members = [EnumMembers!T];
    return members[(uniform(0, members.length))];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import std.random : uniform;
import std.stdio : writefln;
import std.conv;
import std.traits;

enum E {A, B, C}

int main(){
    auto select = [EnumMembers!E][uniform(0, 3)];
    writefln("select %s", select);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: if you need to use the enum values more than once, you can store them in a static immutable array first, otherwise the array will be built every time. That also allows you to get rid of the magic number 3.

```
(...)
int main(){
    static immutable Evalues = [EnumMembers!E];
    auto select1 = Evalues[uniform(0, Evalues.length)];
    writefln("select %s", select1);

    auto select2 = Evalues[uniform(0, Evalues.length)];
    writefln("select %s", select2);
    return 0;
}
```

***Edit 2***: As pointed out by Idan Arye, the template could be even terser:

```
T RandomEnumElement(T)() if (is(T == enum)){
    return [EnumMembers!T][(uniform(0, $))];
}
```

***Edit 3***: *tgehr* has suggested the following solution, which would build the lookup table once at compile time and avoid GC allocation altogether:

```
T RandomEnumElement(T)() if (is(T == enum)) {
    static immutable members = [EnumMembers!T];
    return members[uniform(0, $)];
}
```

Comment: Currently the edit doesn't compile, `Evalues` needs type `E[]`.

Comment: @cmh Strange, it compiles just fine with me. dmd 2.060 win7

Comment: Apologies it does work, it needs the argument when inside a template function.

Comment: Instead of `Evalues.length`(or `3`, which is worse), you can also use the dollar($) sign - which [represents the array's length](http://dlang.org/arrays.html#array-length).